# How to solve the following radical equation?$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}}} =x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> How to solve the following radical equation?
>   $$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}}} =x$$

I'm looking for an easy way to solve it.

Comment: As $0<x<2$

WLOG $x=2\cos t$

Comment: This is just the same as $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}$ is it not? Now it's much easier. All the other answers are way overdoing it. This is the easy way to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Strong hint:**

Notice your equation is the same as $$x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}$$

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: While $x=f(x) \implies x=f(f(x))$, I don't think the implication is reversible. Consider for example $x=\left(x^2-1\right)^2-1$ which has solutions $x=-1, 0, \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, however $x=x^2-1$ only has the solutions $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. It looks like this problem cannot be solved so easily without knowing you have all the possible solutions.

Comment: @Sara Ok so we have $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}.$ Now let's duplicate the equation like so: $$x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\color{red}{x}}}$$ $$x=\color{red}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}}$$ As you can see, we have $\color{red}{x}=\color{red}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}}$ so we can substitute that in the first equation and get: $$x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\color{red}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}}}}$$ which is clearly your equation. Therefore, we have proven that my equation in my answer is the same as your equation, by mere substitution. You might just have to look at it the right way. :)

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}}}=x\implies\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}}=x-2$$$$\implies\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}=2-(x^2-2)^2\implies\sqrt{2-x}=(2-(x^2-2)^2)^2-2$$$$\implies x=2-((2-(x^2-2)^2)^2-2)^2$$

The difference between radicals and powers is that you can expand the right-hand side now and collect like terms. So far this seems pretty easy to me. Unfortunately, I don't think you can solve this one by hand easily once you've expanded and collected, because what you get is:
$$x^{16} - 16 x^{14} + 104 x^{12} - 352 x^{10} + 660 x^{8} - 672 x^{6} + 336 x^{4} - 64 x^{2} + x + 2 = 0$$
According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D2-%28%282-%28x%5E2-2%29%5E2%29%5E2-2%29%5E2), however, there are closed forms for 8 out of 16 solutions, meaning you can use algebraic methods to solve this if you really want to, and the great thing about radicals is that the radicand cannot be negative, so it turns out that the only valid answer to your original equation is $$x=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$$
which is actually the golden ratio. Neat!

Answer (score 1):

As hinted

For real $x,\sqrt{2-x}\ge0\implies x\le2$

But $x=2$ doesn't satisfy the given equation

and $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}}}>0$

So, $0<x,<2$

WLOG let $x=2\cos32t, 0<32t<\dfrac\pi2$

Use $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1=2-2\sin^2x$

$$\sqrt{2-x}=+2\sin16t$$

Now $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}=\sqrt{2(1+\sin16t)}=+\sqrt2(\sin8t+\cos8t)$ as $\sin8t+\cos8t>0$

$\implies\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}=2\cos\left(\dfrac\pi4-8t\right)$

$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}}=\sqrt{2-2\cos\left(\dfrac\pi4-8t\right)}=2\sin\left(\dfrac\pi8-4t\right)$ as $\dfrac\pi8-4t>0$

$\implies\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}}=2\cos\left(4t+\dfrac{3\pi}8\right)$

Finally, $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}}}=\sqrt{2+2\cos\left(4t+\dfrac{3\pi}8\right)}=2\cos\left(2t+\dfrac{3\pi}{16}\right)$

So, we have $$2\cos32t=2\cos\left(2t+\dfrac{3\pi}{16}\right)$$

$$\implies32t=2m\pi\pm\left(2t+\dfrac{3\pi}{16}\right)$$

**Case** $\#1:$ Taking the '+' sign, $$30t=2m\pi+\dfrac{3\pi}{16}=\dfrac{\pi(32m+3)}{16}$$

$$\implies32t=\dfrac{\pi(32m+3)}{16}\cdot\dfrac{32}{30}=\dfrac{\pi(32m+3)}{15}$$

We need $0<\dfrac{\pi(32m+3)}{15}<\dfrac\pi2$

$\iff0<2(32m+3)<15\implies m=0\implies x=2\cos\dfrac{\pi(32\cdot0+3)}{15}$

**Case** $\#2:$ Take the '-' sign

Answer (score 1):

If $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}}} =x$

Then:

$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-x}}}}}}}}=x$

In general:

$x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\ldots}}}}$

Which means that:

$2-(x^2-2)^2=x$

$x^4-4x^2+4+x-2=0$

$x^4-x^3+x^3-x^2-3x^2+3x-2x+2=0$

$(x-1)(x^3+x^2-3x-2)=0$

$(x-1)(x^3+2x^2-x^2-x-2x-2)=0$

$(x-1)(x+2)(x^2-x-2)=0$

$(x-1)(x+2)\left(x - \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$

So the 'possible' answers for x would be :

$\left(1,-2 ,\phi,\dfrac{1}{\phi} \right)$

All are too small to be the answer of the original question except for $\phi$, the golden ratio. So that's the answer.